# Regex statement to replace all underscore with space

Tags: regex, grafana

I can't use methods like Replace so I need a Regex statement that will replace underscores and add a space instead.

I thought that `/([^_])/` would at least return the string without the underscore but it only returns certain strings with the first character.

Comment: [Is this what you're looking for?](https://regex101.com/r/PlizI3/1)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed "_" doesn't seem to work in Grafana.

Comment: you need `/([^_]+)/`

Comment: Replacement is not part of regular expressions. That's something other libraries/programs/functions put on top. So the answer is no, there is no regex that can match and replace at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Sample String `x` is:

```
val x = "this_string_contains_Underscore_characters."
```

Use the below command on this string `x`:

```
x.split("_").mkString(" ")
```

or Use  replaceAll:

```
x.replaceAll("_", " ")
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> val x = "this_string_contains_Underscore_characters."
x: String = this_string_contains_Underscore_characters.

scala> x.split("_").mkString(" ")
res28: String = this string contains Underscore characters.

scala> x.replaceAll("_", " ")
res50: String = this string contains Underscore characters.
```

Comment: I can't use things like "split" and "replace" in Grafana. I need a regex statement that will do exactly what you did for javascript and scala. I'm trying it on this site https://regexr.com/